# Regarding Hibernate LazyInitialization Error

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, orm

I am using `transactions` on `EJB2.0` layer and from there am making call to `DAO` layer wherein am making hibernate calls to db.

Issue am having right now is that hibernate is making multiple calls to database because am setting `lazy="false"`, now i tried to change `lazy="true"` but now am getting our own :

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - the owning Session was closed

error message.

I did some research on `SO` and found that solution could be

```
 <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">30</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size"></prop>
```

and my question is what would be default size of fetch_size and if this is right way to solve this problem.

All i want to do is make sure that application does not make multiple calls to database to run all those `N` queries as right now navigating between page is lot of pain and makes application very slow as on every page click, there are `N` of queries that are run in the background and it increases application load time.

**Update**

Here is the how am setting transactions:

```
 * @hibernate.class table="SCHEDULE_ENTRY" discriminator-value="task" lazy="true"
 * @hibernate.discriminator column="KIND" length="4"
```

Would highly appreciate any suggestions to improve performance of hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - the owning Session was closed
```

You get that exception when you try to access a member of a object (proxy) that has not been initialized yet AND that object is not bound to a session(detached). You have to get rid of that problem first before thinking about changing the batch size.

To get rid of that problem ensure that all the properties you want to access are initialized.
It depends on your transaction/session configuration where you can use lazy loading. It would be helpful if you post your transaction/session configuration.

You can use `Hibernate.initialize()` to initialize members, but i would recommend changing your fetching strategy only where needed.

Take a look at [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-initialization).

I hope i could help :)

Comment: updated question with details regarding how transaction is called.

Answer (score 1):

Access the member of the object before closing the session. Thats the main problem.

Comment: issue here is that am using ejb transaction and calling dao from ejb and so maintaining of session is taken care of by ejb transaction and the thing there are multiple nested queries that are being run and so not sure exactly where the lazy exception is being thrown.